# How do I unit test my reportcontroller by mocking IUserService

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

I have a controller:

```
private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public ReportController ( IOptions<AppSettings> appSettings,
                              UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                              IUserService userService ) : base( appSettings, userManager ) {
        _userService = userService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Report ( string path ) {
        var currentUser = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
        var excludedItems = _userService.GetUserExcludedReportsById( currentUser.Id ).Select( er => er.Path );

        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( path ) || excludedItems.Any( path.Contains ) ) {
            return RedirectToAction( nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home" );
        }

        var customItems = _userService.GetUserCustomReportsById( currentUser.Id ).Select( er => er.Path );

        if ( path.Contains( AppSettings.CustomReportsFolderName ) && !customItems.Any( path.Contains ) ) {
            return RedirectToAction( nameof(HomeController.Index), "Home" );
        }


        var model = GetReportViewerModel( Request );
        model.Parameters.Clear();
        var dbname = _userService.GetDefaultDbName( (await GetCurrentUserAsync()).Id );
        model.Parameters.Add( "connectionStr", new[] {
            dbname
        } );
        model.ReportPath = path;
        model.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Ntlm;

        return View( "Report", model );
    }
}
```

Can you tell me how I approach unit testing this? My main issues are:

It has 3 dependencies in the constructor, I have managed to Mock them apart from the UserManager requirement, which seems to have a large amount of dependencies in itself. I have tried a suggestion from this site, as per below, but the UserManager object complains about missing parameters. I keep getting told It should be simple, but surely I need these to instantiate an instance of the controller?

In terms of what to test on the Report method, my thoughts are: The two IF statements return a redirect. Also the expected return is valid.

So far I have:

```
var mockUserService = new Mock<IUserService>();
        AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings() { };
        IOptions<AppSettings> options = Options.Create(appSettings);
        var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object);
        var mockDependancyResolver = new Mock<IDependencyResolver>();

        var sut = new ReportController(options, userManager.Object, mockUserService.Object);
```

Comment: In the past I haven't bothered going down the "half way" approach of testing the controller by implicitly creating an instance of it. I've actually used an in memory web server (kestrel) to run the framework exactly the way you'd normally run it. So in other words you're sending HTTP requests and verifying responses (you're still mocking ctor dependencies). In this way you have a proper user and HTTP context to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I keep getting told It should be simple

Usually it is simple when your controller depends on abstractions only (i.e. interfaces). Then you can just mock them using `Mock` class. But `UserManager<>` is not abstraction it is a concrete class that can't be mocked by `Mock`. But since most of methods of `UserManager<>` are virtual you can derive from it and override them:

```
public class FakeUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public FakeUserManager()
        : base(new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
              new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
              new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
              new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
              new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
              new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
              new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object)
    { }
    ...
    public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string id)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(new ApplicationUser { Id = id });
    }
    ...
}
```

then use it:

```
var sut = new ReportController(options, new FakeUserManager(), mockUserService.Object);
```